# jQuery append already appended html to div

Tags: jquery, append

I have some HTML appended which has a timer that constantly changes, but I need that timer in another div. Both timers ofcourse must update simultaneosly.

I have picture here below to show you the better example.

[image]

What I have tried so far is this:

```
var time = $('.flashCurrent').html();
$('.thetime').append(time);
```

That doesnt insert anything from .flashCurrent.

The code in the script that appends this is this code:

```
elements.current = $("<div class=\"flashCurrent\"></div>").appendTo(elements.control); // Current elapsed time
```

Comment: `var time = $('.flashCurrent').text();` instead of flashControl?

Comment: My bad, I ment to write .flashCurrent - its not the problem. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an interval to update the value every second (or more frequently to get them more in sync)

```
var sync = setInterval(function() {
    $('.thetime').text($('.flashCurrent').text());
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Well, first I need to get the time inserted into <div class="thetime"></div> which is my problem currently.

Comment: That's covered in the code. It sets the text of .thetime to the text of .flashCurrent.

Comment: I have setup up live, so you can see whats going on.

[link](http://www.restless.dk/play/play.php)

Comment: The solution @Moob laid out has a typo. Change setinterval to setInterval and it will behave as expected.

Comment: Wow, that did it! Thanks! - But shouldnt there be some sort of jquery method that does it live?

Comment: You could create a method that 'watched' for the change but that would involve the same sort of set up (with an interval). Good browsers (>ie8) can listen for the `DOMCharacterDataModified` event and trigger a function when the textNode's text changes. [The accepted answer on this SO question has details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789342/textnode-addeventlistener).

Comment: Oh okay I see, Im learning a lot here. Great. Another thing, how would I redirect when the 'sync' variable has the final time?..

Comment: @Brian I'm not sure what you're asking. It sounds like you want to redirect the page when playback has completed. The jquery.customYtPlayer you are using already contains an `onEnd` option. I suggest you look at using that.

Comment: @Moob yes I have seen that, Ive looked a ton into that file, but I dont get how to pull the options and use them, but I will keep looking. Thanks for your help mate

Comment: @Brian You should really have asked this as a new question but here you go: `$('.youtube').customYtPlayer({onEnd:function(){window.location="somewhere";}});` I've even put it in [a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eGPWR/)

Comment: Okay, on some forums people get mad when asking to much. I cant thank you enough, you have been the best help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.theTime').text(time);
```

Append is generally used to add a new HTML element within the element you have selected.

**Edit:**
I have created a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StXLU/) to show how I believe it should be working.

If this still doesn't work then I suspect there is a scoping issue in how the flashCurrent time is being updated, you may want to investigate jQuery.Live if this is the case.

Comment: That is true, but nothing gets inserted between <div class="thetime"></div> - it just stays empty

Comment: Moob's answer is more complete than mine. It should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the html for `flashControl` div. You only need the text inside of `flashCurrent`

```
var time = $('.flashCurrent').text();
$('.thetime').text(time);
```

Comment: @Brian are you inserting after the time is updated in `flashCurrent`? Try to debug and see what is the value of time while inserting.

Comment: Im thinking the problem might be that the HTML i want to get "is not there" in my source code. Because its appended.

Comment: @Brian - if the source doesn't update the time, then of course, it won't get inserted.

Comment: When I check FireBug the time in between <div class="flashCurrent"></div> does increase. But whatever I try to append the text to 'thetime'-div nothing gets inserted, nothing comes up in FireBug.

Comment: If it's appended it will be 'there' but maybe it doesn't exist until some point *after* you are looking for it. A setinterval could keep trying indefinitely or you could run your script last after everything else has loaded