# How do I copy text from a paragraph element to an input's value without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to copy the text inside a `<p>` element into an `<input>` element's `value` attribute.

The paragraph text contains `.30, .31, .6, .38`, and this text is updated by a jQuery script without refreshing the page, so I need to update the `<input>`'s `value` attribute each time with the new contents of the paragraph:

```
<p id="filter-display">.30, .31, .6, .38</p>
```

The input should look like this after updating it:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tags" value=".30, .31, .6, .38">
```

Is there any way that I can update the input's value attribute to reflect the paragraph's text each time it changes?

Comment: Your tag soup makes it impossible to understand what you're trying to do? Is this client-side javascript that needs to modify the DOM using `jquery`? Or is it server-side `java` or `php` that needs to generate different HTML output? And what does `ajax` have to do with it?

Comment: the ids into #filter-display are generated by jquery, i need the same ids into a hidden input in the same time

Comment: It would help if we could see the logic that was updating the `p` tag.  Also when you say "without recharging", what are you referring to?

Comment: If it is generated by jQuery, and you want the jQuery to *also* generate the hidden input element, then why did you tag `java`, `php`, and `ajax`? They don't seem to have anything whatsoever to do with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to use AJAX to accomplish these updates without refreshing the page in order to modify `#filter-display`'s text content, whenever the paragraph's `TextNode` is updated, you can use the [jQuery val() function](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value) to change the hidden input's value attribute, and apply the appropriate listener (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789342/textnode-addeventlistener)) to the TextNode or paragraph:

```
var $filter_display = $("#filter-display");

$filter_display[0].firstChild.addEventListener("DOMCharacterDataModified", function() {
    $("#my-hidden-input").val($filter_display.text());
});
```

Plain JavaScript:

```
var filter_display_text = document.getElementById("filter-display").firstChild;

filter_display_text.addEventListener("DOMCharacterDataModified", function() {
     document.getElementById("my-hidden-input").value = filter_display_text;
});
```

jQuery unfortunately does not yet have a convenient way to get the actual TextNode of an element, and `text()` returns the actual value of all nested TextNodes in a given element.