# How can I insert a paragraph node with click detection?

Tags: javascript

So I already have the code:

```
function addOpt(opti, id) {
  document.getElementById("options").appendChild(document.createTextNode(opti))
  // ID WILL BE USED LATER
}
```

but I now want to make it so that when you click on the text (opti) it runs a function.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: add the click event listener: `element.addEventListener('click', addOpt);`

Comment: You can't bind events to text node afaik, you need to wrap it in a span or something

Comment: @Yousaf That would work but how would I add an ID to the text node? you need an id for addeventlistener afaik

Comment: @AlonEitan I've done it before with (I cant remember which) either onmousedown = "function()" or onclick = "function()"

Comment: Also use `data-id` attribute and save the `id` there, then read the attribute from within the event callback function

Comment: @AlonEitan Could you please give a code example? I'm not sure I understand

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible to add event listeners to text nodes. source: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789342/textnode-addeventlistener#:~:text=Text%20nodes%20are%20just%20plain,can't%20have%20event%20listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789342/textnode-addeventlistener#:%7E:text=Text%20nodes%20are%20just%20plain,can%27t%20have%20event%20listeners). Correct me if I'm wrong.

```js
function addOpt(opti, id) {
 var a=document.createElement('span');
 a.style.color='blue';
 a.addEventListener('click', (e)=> console.log('clicked'));
 var b= document.createTextNode(opti);
 a.appendChild(b);
  document.getElementById("options").appendChild(a)
  // ID WILL BE USED LATER
}
addOpt('child (click)','id');
```

```html
<div id ='options'>
parent
</div>
```